# Maven build error because of an unresolved Maven POM property used in repository URL when specifying Spring's bill-of-material POM

Tags: maven, repository

I'm facing a reproducible strange behavior when referencing a Maven POM property in the POM's `repositories` section and having a [bill of materials](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) POM (here Spring-Framework-BOM) defined.

Setup to reproduce the problem:

- Maven 3.0.5, JDK 1.7.0.51.x86_64
- Maven POM with a property that holds my Nexus-URL prefix
- that property is referenced in the `pluginRepositories` and `repositories` section
- additionally having `spring-framework-bom` dependency in `dependencyManagement` section defined

The build error occurring in the log:

```
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:4.0.3.RELEASE from/to mycompany.public (${nexus.baseUrl}/content/groups/public/): No connector available to access repository mycompany.public (${nexus.baseUrl}/content/groups/public/) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory @ line 692, column 16
```

Here the excerpt from my Maven POM file:

```
<properties>
  <nexus.baseUrl>http://nexus.mycompanydomain.com</nexus.baseUrl>
  <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>public</id>
    <url>${nexus.baseUrl}/content/groups/public/</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>mycompany.public</id>
    <name>MyCompany Public Repository</name>
    <url>${nexus.baseUrl}/content/groups/public/</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
     <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**Hotfix**
I could solve the problem by replacing the `nexus.baseUrl` by it's value in the `repositories` section of the POM:

```
<repository>
  <id>mycompany.public</id>
  <name>MyCompany Public Repository</name>
  <url>http://nexus.mycompanydomain.com/content/groups/public/</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
```

**Question**
Is anyone able to explain why the resolution of the `nexus.baseUrl` property is not taking place while the `spring.version` property is resolved successfully (see error log)?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the the problem lies in the order of evaluation of the pom.
Properties, like in your case, the property "nexus.baseUrl" are not getting evaluated before the import scope is getting triggered.
In my case, replacing property reference (nexus.baseUrl) in the repository url element with the concrete url solved the problem.